# XMPP intregration with Facebook Chat, using Python

Tags: python, facebook, xmpp, facebook-chat

I'm starting a project using the XMPP protocol and haven't done anything with it thus far. I would like some advice/direction in regards to my questions below.

At the present moment, I know Facebook's Chat API says to use PyXMPP and pyFacebook, which is what I will be using initially. However can someone give me an idea as to how to connect Facebook chat with Gtalk; using their example script, located here:: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

I see that they mention API keys, where exactly do I retrieve the API keys from? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your application at http://developers.facebook.com/apps and get the API keys. Both Gtalk and Facebook chat are built on XMPP protocol. So you can set up an XMPP chat client which will connect to both.

Refer to the book written by Jack Mofitt: http://professionalxmpp.com/

It talks about setting up the chat client. Also the documentation in the Developers forum is bad. Check out this thread from the old forum http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=51892

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the advice. I never knew I would have to register the application, though technically what I'm doing isn't building a application, but more of a service/connector that will allow FB and Gtalk (MSN also in the future) to speak to each other.. That makes sense though. Have you tried connecting to Facebook using the DIGEST-MD5 authentication mechanism? If so, what were your results and how would I go about implementing that method?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can connect using digest MD5, where you need to pass the username and password. Go through the XMPP protocol to get a better understanding on digest MD5.